# Get all current tabs (node view)

Tags: 7, routes

How to get all node tabs (MENU_LOCAL_TASK type) which available for current node?

I mean node/%/edit, node/%/translate, node/%/devel etc.

I've tried to use menu_local_tasks() but it shows only empty array.

Answer (score 3):

Got it!

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $tabs = menu_local_tabs();
}
```